# If excludes url containing www

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, web, window.location

I have the below JavaScript, and when the url (window.location) does **not** contain www. the javascript **IS** executed

```
var windowloc = window.location; // http://mywebsite.com/
var homeurl = "http://mywebsite.com/";
if(windowloc==homeurl){
//JavaScript IS EXECUTED
}
```

and if it **does** the javascript is **not** executed.

```
var windowloc = window.location; // http://www.mywebsite.com/
var homeurl = "http://mywebsite.com/";
if(windowloc==homeurl){
//JavaScript is NOT executed.
}
```

How can I overcome this by allowing the JavaScript to accept urls (window.location) with and without www.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overcome that using regex, as I am sure other answers will provide. However, it's best practice for search engine optimization (SEO) to force your `http://mywebsite.com/` to do a perminant redirect to `http://www.mywebsite.com/` because search engines like Google consider the www. and www-less versions two separate websites.

Then you will not need two separate conditions because your url will always be the www. version.

Comment: Justin what would you recommend, with www. or non-www.

Comment: www. is the standard. I believe all the major sites use the www. version.

Comment: Google, yahoo, and youtube all forward to www. Stackoverflow forwards to the non-www. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use code like this see if the domain has www.mywebsite.com in it:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("//www.mywebsite.com/") != -1) {
     // code to execute if it is www.mywebsite.com
} else {
     // code to execute if it is not www.mywebsite.com
}
```

or, you could use just the hostname part of window.location like this to just check for the "www.":

```
if (window.location.hostname.indexOf("www.") != -1) {
     // code to execute if it is www. something
} else {
     // code to execute if it is not www. something
}
```

or if you wanted to check for exactly your entire domain, you could do it like this:

```
if (window.location.hostname === "www.mywebsite.com" {
     // code to execute if it is www.mywebsite.com
} else {
     // code to execute if it is not www.mywebsite.com
}
```

Comment: But he is only wanting to detect if the user is on the home page. And I don't think he wants an `else`.

Comment: I thought he was just trying to detect if it was `www.` or not on any page (the first line of the question just says to execute JS when there's no `www`).  The question is not particularly clear.  As for the `else`, the OP can certainly do what they want to with that.  I added it for clarity in the comments.  As for only on the homepage, the OP could include this code only on the homepage if they wanted or could do a fuller URL check.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("://www") === -1) {
    // "www" excluded
} else {
    // other stuff
}
```

edited the code sample to be more specific

Comment: He was asking for a way to not need multiple statements. Besides, that will detect `www` anywhere in the URL, which is not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('mywebsite.com')!= -1){
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: All this would do is detect whether the current page was somewhere on the mywebsite.com site.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `hostname` property of the `location` object to determine what address you're being served under:

```
if (location.hostname==='mywebsite.com')
    // do something
```

`location` and other address-owning objects like links have properties like `hostname`, `pathname`, `search` and `hash` to give you the already-parsed pieces of the URL, so you don't have to try to pick apart URL strings yourself. Don't just look for the presence of `www.` in the location string as it might be somewhere else in the string that isn't the hostname.

But +1 Justin's answer: if you are trying to redirect alternative addresses such as a non-www address to a canonical address, the right way to do that is with an HTTP 301 redirect and not anything to do with JavaScript. This would normally be configured at the server level, eg for Apache you might use a `Redirect` in your `.htaccess`.